# How can I make upstream exceptions return UnprocessableEntityResult with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

When a request comes in to my ASP.NET Core API controller that is properly formed, but can't be processed because of some sort of business rule that throws an exception when violated, I want to return a 422 HTTP response with error text in the body.  I would like this to work across many actions on my controller without adding code such as a try/catch block to each of them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's a concise answer, but it has to be implemented in every controller action.  This example can be implemented once and work across the application.  But you've got a good point and I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score -1):

It may be easiest to implement an `IAsyncExceptionFilter` in your application - this can pick up unhandled exceptions on controller actions and rewrite them into a form you'd like, such as the 422 HTTP response desired here. If implementing an `IAsyncExceptionFilter` you can use the below code which was tested with ASP.NET Core 3.1 to return the exception message to the client as plain text:

```cs
public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context) {
  if (!context.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted) {
    var errorMessage = "Could not do that because of X reason."; // or you could use `context.Exception.Message` if it is secure in your application to do so
    var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(errorMessage).AsMemory();
    context.Result = new UnprocessableEntityResult();
    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 422;
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = responseBytes.Length;
    await context.HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(responseBytes);
    context.ExceptionHandled = true;
  } else {
     // if the response has already started, this can't be used.  You will have to figure
     // out a different solution.
  }
}
```

If not using an `IAsyncExceptionFilter`, you can still use most of the above code, it would be a matter of setting the same properties on the `Response.HttpContext` object available in your controller's handler, and then returning the `UnprocessableEntityResult`.

Note that setting both the `ContentType` and `ContentLength` headers correctly will prevent `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` errors with some browsers.  In this case, the `ContentLength` will be accurate because we get the bytes of the error string from `Encoding.UTF8` first and set the `ContentLength` to the length of those bytes, not just the string length.  Also, the `ContentType` header includes the `charset=UTF-8` qualifier to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Or you could just `context.Result = new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(context.Exception.Message);` and remove the rest of the code, by using the appropriate class. *ObjectResult are the classes used to return data. You even avoid manually modifying the response (ugh)